# Why does this code not output the winner variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a dice game for my Computer Science GCSEs and am relatively new to python. When trying to conditionally assign a new variable to an existing variable, the code runs until outputting the new variable where it returns Name Error. Can somebody please suggest any solutions?

```
class player:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.name = "foo"

if player1.score > player2.score:
    winner = player1.name

elif player2.score < player1.score:
    winner = player2.name

print(winner)
```

Should output "foo", but instead gives Name Error: name "winner" is not defined.

Comment: Hmm the code you post gives error messages anyway, please try to give a reproducible piece of code.

Comment: that's because the scope of  winner is only within elif and you try to access it outside it

Comment: @TausifShaikh please learn about python's scoping rules...

Comment: Your code snippet makes no sense and is not even syntactically correct. Please post a minimal, complete and reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Your code still fails to tick the "complete" and "reproducible" requirements. Just a hint though: if both players scores are equal, neither the if nor the elif blocks will be executed, and `winner` will indeed not be defined.

Comment: What is `player1`? What is `player2`? Why do you have the same condition in the `if` and `elif` block? How do you expect `winner` to be set if `player1.score <= player2.score`?

Comment: This question seems to have been edited, possibly with a working solution. This is not ideal - we need questions to contain questions - any answer material can go below.

Comment: In the absence of a discussion about the question, I have rolled this back to what I think was the last good question state. This will ensure that the answers provided below are reasonable responses to the question (as opposed to solutions to a solution with no question).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try:

```
import random
class player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = random.randint(1,6)
        print(self.name, self.score)

player_1 = player("Richard")
player_2 = player("Bob")
winner =''
if player_1.score > player_2.score:
    winner = player_1.score 
    print(winner)
elif player_2.score> player_1.score:
    winner = player_2.score 
    print(winner)
else:
    print("Tie.")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: forgot to add that player(2) to my question

Comment: Do you want the player score created in the construction?

Comment: It already is, but I tried (and clearly failed) to make the displayed code as short as possible

Comment: @Jonathan your code snippet should indeed be as minimal as possible, but it still have to be correct and complete (and of course it has to reproduce your issue...).

Comment: I just updated the code, I think this should be what you are going for.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to assign the greater score to a variable (I'm using winner) for my code to work.

Comment: winner points to the greater score now. If you want it to point to the name of the winner, use player_1.name or player_2.name.

Answer (score -1):

Let me guide you

```
class player:
    self.name = "foo"

elif player2.score < player1.score:
    winner = player2.name

print(winner)
```

If you see your code clearly. You have defined winner inside elif. This means that the code outside it do not know what is "winner". So you need to define winner outside elif.

```
winner = ''
class player:
    self.name = "foo"

elif player2.score < player1.score:
    winner = player2.name

print(winner)
```

Comment: So I defined winner initially in an if statement, do I still have to define it outside that?

Comment: yes, See the below code that i wrote. I have defined winner globally. So that print knows there is something of name winner.